# Get group name as a axis in graph matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot graph between location and number of companies present in that location.

```
 # split data on basis of group
 location_group = fortune_df.groupby('Location')
 # pick top 10 location with maximum location
 location_withmax_no_of_companies = location_group.size().sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]
  Location
New York, NY         72
Houston, TX          44
Atlanta, GA          23
Chicago, IL          22
Dallas, TX           16
St. Louis, MO        14
San Francisco, CA    11
Cleveland, OH        11
San Jose, CA         10
Columbus, OH         10
dtype: int64

lpos = np.arange(10)
plt.xticks(lpos,location_withmax_no_of_companies)
plt.bar(lpos,location_withmax_no_of_companies)
```

[image]

I want name of location instead of number(x-axis), But not getting how to give to give name in x-axis. Any lead will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas for ploting with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
location_withmax_no_of_companies.plot.bar()
```

Or change `location_withmax_no_of_companies` for `location_withmax_no_of_companies.index` for change labels by indices of `Series`:

```
plt.xticks(lpos,location_withmax_no_of_companies.index)
```

If need also rotate labels:

```
plt.xticks(lpos,location_withmax_no_of_companies.index, rotation=90)
```